Integrating $\,\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{x \sin^{-1}x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm dx\,$ by parts
$$I = \int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{(x \sin^{-1}(x))}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} \mathrm dx$$ is the given problem.
Such problems are usually solved by the trigonometric substitution, $$x \rightarrow \sin(\theta) ; \mathrm dx \rightarrow \cos(\theta) \mathrm d\theta,$$ this method gives the correct answer of $$\frac{6- \pi \sqrt{3}}{12}.$$
However, I wanted to try solving it using integration by parts:$$\int u \, \mathrm dv = uv- \int v \, \mathrm du.$$
I let $$ x \sin^{-1}(x) = u$$ and $$\frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} = \mathrm dv.$$
This gives us $$\mathrm du = \left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \sin^{-1}(x)\right) \mathrm dx $$ and $$v=\sin^{-1}(x).$$
This gives us
$$\begin{align}
I &= \left(x \sin^{-1}(x) \times \sin^{-1}(x)\right)\Bigg \rvert_0^{1/2} - \int_0^{1/2} \left(\sin^{-1}(x)\times\left(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} + \sin^{-1}(x)\right)\right) \mathrm dx \\
&= \frac{{\pi}^2}{72}-\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{(x \sin^{-1}(x))}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}}\mathrm dx - \int_{0}^{1/2} {\sin^{-1}(x)}\times{\sin^{-1}(x)}\mathrm dx
\end{align}$$
i.e:
$$I = \frac{{\pi}^2}{72} - I - I_2 \Rightarrow 2I = \frac{{\pi}^2}{72} - I_2. $$
Now solving for $$I_2 =\int_{0}^{1/2} {\sin^{-1}(x)}\times{\sin^{-1}(x)}\mathrm dx.$$ Using integration by parts again, we get:
let $$u_2 = {\sin^{-1}(x)}\times{\sin^{-1}(x)}$$ and $$\mathrm dv_2= \mathrm dx \Rightarrow \mathrm du_2 = \frac{2 \sin^{-1}(x)}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \mathrm dx$$ and $$v_2 = x.$$
This gives us $$I_2 = \left(x \sin^{-1}(x) \times \sin^{-1}(x)\right)\Bigg \rvert_0^{1/2}-\int_{0}^{1/2}\frac{(2x \sin^{-1}(x))}{\sqrt{(1-x^2)}} \mathrm dx \Rightarrow I_2 =\frac{{\pi}^2}{72} - 2I.$$
Substituting this in the original equation and solving, we get $$I=\frac{{\pi}^2}{144}$$ which is clearly incorrect. Where was the mistake in my method??

see - https://math.stackexchange.com/q/801765/1157207

How did you solve by substitution? You've just found the equation $I_2+2I=\frac{\pi^2}{72}$ twice, not two equations that can be solved for $I$.

I'm not seeing where you got $I=\pi^2/144$ from. Everything you've written seems correct until the last claim.

it seems i had made a mistake while solving in my notebook , i have indeed gotten the equation $$I_2+2I=\frac{{\pi}^2}{72}$$ twice , meaning im still stuck . is this question not solvable by parts then , and we will have to make a subsitution??

$$ \begin{align} &\begin{cases} du=\frac{x,dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} &\implies u=-\sqrt{1-x^2} \ v=\sin^{-1}x &\implies dv=\frac{dx}{\sqrt{1-x^2}} \end{cases} \ \color{red}{I} &=-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sin^{-1}x + \int dx \ &=\color{red}{x-\sqrt{1-x^2}\sin^{-1}x} \end {align} $$
